# Are people allowed to link to their portfolio and/or resume?

Tags: discussion

re: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/68094/how-to-get-hired-as-a-web-designer

Is providing links to your personal website/portfolio/resume within a question permitted?

Seems like a way to get free advertising.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, as long as the contents of their portfolio/resume are relevant** to the question. Which will be almost never.

The workplace isn't a resume reviewing service and we shy away from providing situation-specific advice that's only useful for the OP and no one else. As a result, most question where the details of someone's resume would be important will not be on-topic. The [question that prompted this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/68094/how-to-get-hired-as-a-web-designer?noredirect=1) is a good example. Off the top of my head the only time I'd expect a link to either is when they're used as an example for a generic question. Something like "*should I include an [X] section in my resume?*" or "*Is a personal branding website like [this] useful?*"

StackExchange has a fairly high tolerance when it comes to linking resources that could be considered advertising and the only criteria that need to be met are relevance and disclosure (to avoid spam flags). As an example, a well-known Personal Finance user routinely answers question with links to his personal site where he goes into further detail on a particular subject. He discloses his affiliation and provides a useful resource as an addition to his answer which makes this kind of "advertising" beneficial for all parties involved. This mainly applies to Answers but we can draw a parallel to Questions as well: **as long as the link adds to the question the minor link/advertising boost should be considered a worthwhile trade.**

Comment: Suggestion: put links in the about-you section of your profile?

Comment: @keshlam Isn't that a separate issue though? Joe's asking about linking from a question and either the link is relevant to the post and should be featured there or it doesn't deserve to be included. Or are you suggesting linking from the profile to avoid link building?